# Is $\mathcal{O} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p} F$ a finite direct product of fields?

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

Consider the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and residue field $\mathbb{F}_p$. Let us take a finite  extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ and $k$ be the residue field of $K$. Let $\pi \in \mathcal{O}_K$ be a uniformizer. Consider the ring of power series $\mathfrak{S}\mathrel{:=}W(k)[[u]]$, where $W(k)$ is the ring of Witt vectors on the residue field $k$. Let $\mathcal{O}:=\widehat{\mathfrak{S}[\frac{1}{u}]}$ be the $p$-adic completion of $\mathfrak{S}[\frac{1}{u}]$. Also let $F$ be finite field.

Then $\mathcal{O} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p} F$ decomposes as a product of fields.

**Question:**
Is $\mathcal{O} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p} F$ a *finite* product of fields ? Or an *arbitrary* product of fields ?

For example, $W(k) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p} W(k)$ is a finite ($[k: \mathbb{F}_p]$ copies) direct product of $W(k)$.

But I couldn't conclude  the question.

Any hints please

Comment: The basic case would be $F=\mathbb F_p$. Do you know what the tensor product is in that case? (Hint: It should be one field.) Then you should derive the general case from there, writing it as tensor product of that basic case, over $\mathbb F_p$, with a finite extension of that.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, so, when $F$ is finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$, the above tensor product would be finite direct product of fields. Isn't it ?

Comment: You didn't use $\pi$ @TorstenSchoeneberg

Comment: @reuns it's reasonable not to use $\pi$ because $\pi$ doesn't actually get used in the definition of $\mathcal O$ or anywhere else in the actual question being asked. You didn't use $\pi$ yourself in the answer you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but $W(k)= O_L=\Bbb{Z}_p[\zeta_{q-1}]$ where $L=\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{q-1}),q=|k|$ is the largest unramified extension $\subset K$ $$\mathfrak{S}[\frac{1}{u}]=O_L[[u]][u^{-1}]=\{ \sum_{n\ge -N} a_n u^n, a_n\in O_L\}$$ whose $p$-adic completion is $$\mathcal{O} = \{ \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n u^n, a_n\in O_L, \lim_{n\to -\infty} v_p(a_n)=\infty\}$$
Note that $\mathcal{O}/(p)=\Bbb{F}_q((u))$.

For a finite field $F$, when $char(F)\ne p$ then $\mathcal{O}\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}_p}F=\mathcal{O}/(char(F))\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}_p}F=0$,

when $char(F)=p,F=\Bbb{F}_p[x]/(f(x))$ then $$\mathcal{O}\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}_p}F=\mathcal{O}/(p)\otimes_{\Bbb{F}_p}\Bbb{F}_p[x]/(f(x))$$ $$=\Bbb{F}_q((u))\otimes_{\Bbb{F}_p} \Bbb{F}_p[x]/(f(x))=\Bbb{F}_q((u))[x]/(f(x))$$ $$=\Bbb{F}_q((u))[x]/(\prod_j f_j(x))=\prod_j\Bbb{F}_q((u))[x]/(f_j(x))=\prod_j \Bbb{F}_{q^{\deg(f_j)}}((u))$$

Comment: I assume $f_j$ are the irreducible factors of $f$ over $\mathbb F_q$?

Comment: Yes, distinct maximal thus comaximal ideals

Comment: @reuns, Thanks for your nice answer. Can you explain why $\mathcal{O}\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}_p}F=\mathcal{O}/(char(F))\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}_p}F$ ? I think the later tensor product should be over $\mathbb{F}_p$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: $char(F)\otimes 1 = 1\otimes char(F)=1\otimes 0=0$ so we can quotient by (the ideal generated by) $char(F)\otimes 1$.

Comment: @reuns, ohh, nice. Thank you very much